# bin/hive giving issue with the errors

Tags: java, hive

I have installed the hive using source and run ant package.

as per **cwiki.apache.org** document, I have added `PATH` var also i.e `$HIVE_HOME` and `$PATH` but running the command from base directory (bin/hive or hive)

It give the following error.
I have added the patch (**HIVE-3606.1.patch**) to resolve it but still it's not working.

Command to add patch:

```
hive-0.10.0-bin]$ patch -p0 < ~/Downloads/HIVE-3606.1.patch
```

To run Hive:

```
hive-0.10.0-bin]$ bin/hive

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFJSONTuple.<clinit>(GenericUDTFJSONTuple.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 4):

It's most probably because your Hadoop uses a different (older) version of Jackson libraries than Hive. As a quick workaround you can replace `jackson-core-asl-X-X-X.jar` and `jackson-mapper-asl-X.X.X.jar` in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` with the newer ones in `$HIVE_HOME/lib`

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are working with old version of Hadoop.

If you have Hadoop, its better to compile the source code yourself with the following command for old version of Hadoop:

```
$ svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk hive
$ cd hive
$ mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist
```

Check this link for more info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

Then, change the jackson* file names in $HADOOP_HOME/lib and add an .old postfix to them (Its a good practice not to delete them, as we may want them in future):

```
$ mv jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar  jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar.old
$ mv jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar.old
```

You can find the new jackson compiled files somewhere around Hive's packaging folder, mine is in:

```
packaging/target/apache-hive-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/apache-hive-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/hcatalog/share/webhcat/svr/lib
```

If you can't find it, its ok. use the following command in your hive directory.

```
$ find ./ -iname "*jackson*"
```

It will show you all the jackson* files that it can find. Then go to that specific folder that contains them and copy all of them to the $HADOOP_HOME/lib (currently we may just need the "jackson-core-*" but we copy all for future use):

```
$ cp jackson* $HADOOP_HOME/lib
```

Ask if you have more enquiries.